# ArrayList in Java - check elements partially

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a simple question regarding `ArrayList` in Java.

I have a simple `ArrayList`. Now I want to check, if the `ArrayList` contains a certain string. I know that `contains()` checks the object as a whole, but I want to check if a part of the object has the string that I'm looking for.

So what is the best way to achieve this? My Sample here says `False` and I want it to say `True`.
How?

```
ArrayList<String> test_al = new ArrayList();
test_al.add("hello world");

if(test_al.contains("hello")){
    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"True");
}
else{
    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"False");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you have to iterate over the list. It's better to create a separate method:

```
static boolean hasSubstring(Collection<String> c, String substring) {
    for(String s : c) {
        if(s.contains(substring))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
    ArrayList<String> test_al = new ArrayList();
    test_al.add("hello world");

    if(hasSubstring(test_al, "hello")){
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"True");
    }
    else{
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"False");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`list.contains()` check for the whole match in the list entry.

What you want to do is to check if the subString existed in the list of `Strings`

For that you need to iterate through the list and check if an entry consists of the substring wanted.

```
public boolean contains(List<String> list, String key){
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
  if(list.get(i).contains(key))
     return true;
   }
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple iteration trough the elements of your array like this for example:

```
ArrayList<String> test_al = new ArrayList();
boolean contains = false;
for(String el : test_al){
    // if you find an element that has the "hello" in it, stop the loop
    if(el.indexOf("hello") > -1){
        contains = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 SDK, the new Stream API has a method for this case:

```
test_al.stream().anyMatch(i->i.contains("hello"));
```